# Custom Jquery script to hide fields inside my New & Edit form is not working on Iphone safari web browser

Tags: development, javascript, jquery, form, mobile

I have defined the following jQuery script to hide some columns inside my Edit & New built-in forms:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Item Number")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Customer Initials")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Recurrence")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Workspace")').closest('tr').hide();
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("All Day Event")').closest('tr').hide();




});
```

now the script is working as expected inside my desktop browsers including ; IE,firefox, safari.

but when i access the Edit and New forms from my iphone 5s using safari web browser , then the script will not hide any column and all the above fields will be shown .. so can anyone adivce why the jquery script is not having any effect on iphone web browser ?

Comment: Could it be that the markup is not the same, or the DOM is not created the same way (e.g., `nobr` is never created either way)? You need some way of remote console, perhaps [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591974). Then you could inspect the DOM and run queries

Comment: now the custom script will work as expected if i access the pages from Safari on eithermy desktop or using PC view from my mobile. while it will not work if i switch to mobile view on my mobile device.. not sure how i can inspect the DOM on my iphone safar.. also this will raise a problem in my case if i want to be hiding the columns differently on each browser and mobile device,, so is there a more formal way to accomplish this, i mean to hide the column on the relevant New & Edit forms ?

Comment: @eirikb now i inspect the markup inside the mobile forms,, but seems i can not add custom script to the mobile forms .. as i did in the regular forms

Answer (score 1):

If it's Safari on Iphone, then add classic way of getting elements & then hide them like

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: can you advice why my approach will not work on iphone safari , and why i need to use document.getelementByID instead?

Comment: @Daniel Ziga now seems that the edit & new forms that are going to be rendered inside my mobile device have names different that the ones rendered inside my PC view. they will have names such as editforma.aspx & newforms.aspx and i can not access or even see these forms inside SharePoint designer,, can u adivce ? as how i will add the custom script to the mobile forms while i can not access them from the sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile view does not use the same markup, you can test this in your desktop browser by adding `Mobile=1` to the URL.

A field will look like this:

```
<div class="mb-list-detail-property-panel">
        <div class="mb-list-property-name">
            UnitId
        </div><div class="mb-list-property-value">
            <input name="UnitId_TextBox" type="text" maxlength="19" id="UnitId_TextBox" /><br /><span id="ctl701" class="mb-form-field-validate" style="font-size:12px;color:red;display:none;"></span><span id="ctl702" class="mb-form-field-validate" style="font-size:12px;color:red;display:none;"></span><span id="ctl703" class="mb-form-unique-validate" style="font-size:12px;color:red;display:none;">This value already exists in the list.</span>
        </div>
```

Update:

You can set the ShowInNewForm/ShowInEditForm properties. This could be done with all of the object models.

Using JSOM you could do it like this:

```
 SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName");

    var fields =list.get_fields();

    var fieldToHide = fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("Field1");
    fieldToHide.setShowInEditForm(false);
    fieldToHide.setShowInNewForm(false);
    fieldToHide.update();

    clientContext.load(fieldToHide);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
        console && console.log("Success");
    }, function(sender, args) {
        console && console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + ' ' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
    });

 });
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the info about adding Mobile=1 to the URL . Now i found many online tutorials that hide columns using custom scripts same as i am currently doing. but seems those tutorials did not take into consideration mobile views, or that hiding column based on class name will not work on regular and mobile views at the same time

Comment: ...so my question is divided into two parts; how i can hide columns using javaScript and make sure that the script will work on mobile & PC views ? second question, i wrote custom script to hide these column, because these columns will be shown again when users modify them (such as changing their defualt value) so i can not reply on hiding them from the content type. so my question is what is the formal way to hide these column only from the edit & New forms , while keeping them inside the view form, other than writing custom scripts that will be rendered inside the related forms ?

Comment: What do you mean with they will be show again when they modify them, will they be show in newform/editform again then? There are properties on the fields to hide them from only newform/editform, but still visible from dispform, views etc

Comment: i mean if you set a column as hidden from the content type, and then you edit the column (for example chnage its defualt value). then the column will be set as optional inside the content type.. this what i mean//

Comment: so how i can hide the column from the new/edit but keep it inside the display form ? can you adivce more on this? Because if i hide it from the content type settings it will be hidden on all the forms...

Comment: @johnG updated my answer, hope its what you are looking for.

Comment: can u  please advice how i will execute this JSOM script ?

Comment: Well, since its a property on the fields in the list, and only needs to run it one time, you could just run it from your debug console. If its a lot of list in different webs etc. You could use a powershell script.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your reply, seems the script is exaclty what i am looking for. now i have the following 2 questions; what are the differences between JSOM and JSLink are they the same ? second question i need your script to apply to my site column at the custom site content type is this possible? this mean the site column will not get affected only the site column inside the custom content type will be hidden on new & edit forms ? can you adivce on these pleaee?

Comment: JSOM is javascript object model, JSLink is just a property on an object with a link to a javascript file that will run more or less. And on your second question, no thats not possible im afraid. A content type does not contain a SPField object, just a SPFieldLink to the Site Column. The only property available on the FieldLink is Hidden (the same you have in the GUI). You could set the property on the Site Column only.